# Divide One Object Property Value by Another (AngularJS)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat for data values from an object.

```
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="number in numbers">
    <li><span ng-bind="number.first"></span></li>
    <li><span ng-bind="number.second"></span></li>
    <li><span ng-bind="number.third"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

One of the object property values is dependent on the value of other property values (I want the value of third to be first / second).

```
.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.numbers = [
        {
        first: 8,
        second: 5,
        third: ? (I need this to be first / second)
        },

        {
        first: 4,
        second: 5,
        third: ? (I need this to be first / second)
        }
  ];

});
```

I must have set this up fundamentally wrong because I find it hard to imagine it should be this difficult and I haven't worked with AngularJS or js in general much in the past 12 months so chances are I've gone about the ng-repeat all wrong.

Comment: Do this in view => `<li><span ng-bind="number.first/number.second"></span></li>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in view by dividing first key with the second (`<li><span ng-bind="number.first/number.second"></span></li>`) or use [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) in the controller.

> A [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) is a method that gets the value of a specific property.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.numbers = [{
    first: 8,
    second: 5,
    get third() {
      return this.first / this.second
    }
  }, {
    first: 4,
    second: 5,
    get third() {
      return this.first / this.second
    }
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MainController">
  <ul ng-repeat="number in numbers">
    <li><span ng-bind="number.first"></span>
    </li>
    <li><span ng-bind="number.second"></span>
    </li>
    <li><span ng-bind="number.third"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/q6Ltuc0c/)

Comment: This does the job perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the third number in the object but it could be `null` or you could not even have it in the object at all. You an do it like this:

```
$scope.numbers = [
  {
    first: 8,
    second: 5,
    third: null /* you do not actually need this at all */
  },
  {
    first: 4,
    second: 5,
    third: null
  }
];

<ul ng-repeat="number in numbers">
  <li><span ng-bind="number.first"></span></li>
  <li><span ng-bind="number.second"></span></li>
  <li><span ng-bind="(number.first / number.second)"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works well but the getter method mentioned by the accepted answer gives me greater control for sorting etc. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yep, I think so too. No problem and all the best!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("myctrl" , function($scope){
  
 $scope.numbers = [
        {
        first: 8,
        second: 5,
      
        },

        {
        first: 4,
        second: 5,
      
        }
 ];

});
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
   

  
  <body>    
 <div ng-app="app">       
 <div ng-controller="myctrl">
     <ul ng-repeat="number in numbers">
      <li><span ng-bind="number.first"></span></li>
      <li><span ng-bind="number.second"></span></li>
      <li><span ng-bind="number.first/number.second"></span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
 
  </body>
  
  
</html>
```